# Selenium with ruby how to identify an object by its type? e.g <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="">

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ruby

Selenium  with ruby how to identify an object by its type? e.g

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="">
```

What is the ruby code to identify this kind of element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify an element by it's type using CSS and passing in the type as the locator. In this case I'm using find_element to do identify it:

`@driver.find_element(css: '[type="text"]')`

You could also do this for the name attribute:

`@driver.find_element(css: '[name="FirstName"]')`